# Can't upload to SAMD21 over SWD port. Tried Black Magic Probe and Atmel-ICE, Arduino IDE and PlatformIO

Tags: samd21

I must be missing something here. I’m unable to upload to a SAMD21 microcontroller with either a Black Magic Probe (v2.1) or Atmel-ICE. I have tried using both Arduino IDE and PlatformIO and haven’t had any success. I am mostly hoping to program an Adafruit Trinket m0 using a pogo pin fixture which connects to the SWD and SWC pads on the bottom of the Trinket m0. I have been able to program these Trinket m0s over USB, but my application requires the USB port to be removed. I have also tried to program an MKR 1000, and a custom SAMD21 PCB (that someone else was able to program on their computer) using the 10 pin jTag/SWD interface and gotten similar results.

I have tried uploading with PIO and the Black Magic Probe both with and without the upload_port option specified, using both ports that appear when the Black Magic Probe is connected. I have looked for how to use the Black Magic Probe with Arduino IDE, and I have found examples of them being used together, but haven’t found instructions on how to add the Black Magic Probe to the list of programmers supported by Arduino IDE. I have tried the normal upload option with the Black Magic Probe by specifying either of the COM ports that appear when it is plugged in.

When I connect Atmel-ICE and look in the device manager it says the drivers are not installed. I have tried searching automatically and manually online and have not found them.

I am including pastes of the uploader output for both Arduino IDE and PIO using both the Black Magic Probe and Atmel-ICE, uploading to the Trinket m0:

PIO, Atmel-ICE: https://pastebin.com/mcKLt0kU
Arduino IDE: Atmel-ICE: https://pastebin.com/4S1VY0mG
PIO, BMP: https://pastebin.com/XByDshRh
Arduino IDE, BMP: https://pastebin.com/RJtMKQhx

Comment: Just out of my head I remember that all SAM require a 1k pull-up on the SWDCLK line. Is it present?

Comment: Thanks @KarlKarlsom
It doesn't look like this resistor is present in either the Trinket m0 or the MKR 1000. I tried uploading to the MKR 1000 using the Atmel-ICE with a resistor between VDD and SWDCLK and got the same result.